# When are vals evaluated exactly?

Tags: scala

Considering *regular* `val`s (not `lazy` ones) - when are they evaluated exactly?

For classes and singleton objects, I believe this is when the class/object gets instantiated. And for traits, when a class implementing said trait gets instantiated. For package objects, I'm not sure.

```
class Test {
  val someList = (1 to 1000)   // evaluated when it's Test is instantiated
}

object Test {
  val someList = (1 to 1000)   // evaluated when Test gets instantiated
}

trait Test {
  val someList = (1 to 1000)   // evaluated when a class implementing Test is instantiated
}

package object Test {
  val someList = (1 to 1000)   // ???
}
```

Also, given that a `def` and `lazy val` are both evaluated when first accessed, is the only main difference between them that the `val` is only evaluated once?

```
class Test {
  lazy val someList = (1 to 1000)   // evaluated at access time, once
  def someList = (1 to 1000)    // evaluated at access time for each access
}
```

From a performance perspective, my current assumption is that there is essentially no difference between the first access of a `def` or `val` (of the same thing), but subsequent accesses of an already evaluated `val` will be quicker (assuming whatever being evaluated is measurably large).

Hence, if I have a large list that I need evaluating only once, then I should use a `val` (and if not certain that it will ever be used, and performance of first access is not a problem for me, then a `lazy` one)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, all correct. Package objects behave like normal objects with respect to initialisation.

Comment: Cheers for the confirmation.